# Sorting gridview clears gridview when databinding from code behind

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, gridview, binding

I have an ASP.net C# page that uses a stored procedure in a single SQL query to return multiple tables.

I then bind each GridView in the page to the corresponding table from the query:

```
grdCustomers.DataSource = objDS.Tables[3];
grdCustomers.DataBind();
```

This works well but clears out the data when you sort the GridView columns. I understand I need to bind the data again on post-back but I'm not sure of an easy way to do this since the GridViews are not bound on page load now.

What's the easiest way to keep the GridView binding on sort as well as sort the columns correctly when binding the data in code behind?

Comment: _"since the gridviews are not bound on page load now"_ why not, when are they bound? Instead of loading a large DataSet write methods that return a `DataTable`, one for every grid. Then you can call all those methods on the first load(`!IsPostBack`). On consecutive postbacks like the one from the sorting you would just call the related method which returns a single table.

Comment: There is a dropdown selection to choose the value to pass to the stored procedure. This is what binds the gridview.

Comment: @TimSchmelter not quite following your comment.

Comment: I still dont get why you can't reload the data-source from the grid with the correct sort

Comment: Why don't you sort the DataTable instead of the gridview?